# How can I correct this error: Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: php, database, ms-access, web, odbc

I have a website that runs in Windows server, and it works perfectly fine. I tried to make a copy in my localhost but I get the error:

```
Warning: odbc_connect() [function.odbc-connect]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in C:\xampp\htdocs\tdms\webfolders\secured\db_fns.php on line 29
 Could not connect to database server
```

line 29 contains:

```
function fgsdb_connect()
{

   $a=array();
   $retvar=0;

   $result = odbc_connect('FGS','tdms','tdms358',SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC); //---->line 29

   if (!$result) // cannot establish connection to database

     throw new Exception('Could not connect to database server');

   else // connection to database has been established

     return $result;

}
```

I am really new to odbc. the website is written in php and the database that i use in mySQL. though i figured that the database that it is trying to connect is a microsoft access MDE file. (i checked in the site in windows server.) What should i do? im sorry but i am really

Comment: what do you mean? im sorry. i am really a newbie. :(

Comment: permissions: i.e. does the identity that the page is running as hace access to the database?

Comment: You need to use the ODBC Data Source manager to define your connection.

Comment: i opened my data source manager. the user dns has dBase driver, excel driver and microsoft access driver. the system dns has only SQL server driver. i tried configuring the drivers in the user dns but it says that the driver cannot be found.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a MySQL database with a MS SQL ODBC data source? Your post seems to mention both or is it a typo?

Comment: i am trying to connect to a ms access MDE database using odbc. the ODBC driver in the system dns is only sql server.

Comment: I searched and found out that the i dont have the microsoft access driver for me to use and actually access the datasource. now i need to know how to install the microsoft access driver in my odbc system dns.

Comment: You can get the Access ACE drivers free (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255) and these are backwardly compatible, but I wonder if you may have another problem, an mde typically contains forms, reports, code but little or no data, the data will be held in another location.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely the shortcut for setting ODBC data sources is pointing to the 32bit data sources instead of 64bit.

Go to control panel -> administrative tools --> select data sources(ODBC) --> then right click on that file --> go to properties --> in the shortcut tab -> change the path from

```
%windir%\System32\odbcad32.exe
```

to

```
%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

and make your connection. the driver for MS Access will work fine now.

If it doesnt work, try to connect to the ODBC with a sentence like this:

```
$conn = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=C:\YourFolder\YourFile.mdb",'Youruser', 'YourPassword');
```

The last 2 leave then just the the '' if you dont have any user or password

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error on PHP 7.0.8 64bit while trying to connect to an Access .mdb.

I had to do two things:

1. Install the 64bit version of "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" (even with Access 2016 installed I was getting your error).  You can download the driver from:

   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

   Then, if you go to the ODBC Data Source Administrator, you should notice the 64bit version.
2. Change the driver string to:

   `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}`

Hope it helps other people.