# MS Access DB in php 64bit SQL state IM002 error

Tags: php, ms-access

I'm trying to fetch data from access db in php. Code works fine for 32 bit php( I've tested in php version>5), but code generates error for 64bit php wamp.

Error Message: `Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in`

What I've tried : [How can I correct this error: Data source name not found and no default driver specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122611/how-can-i-correct-this-error-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-s)

Code :

```
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$db", "","");
$tabs = odbc_tables($connection);
```

Is there any solution or I've to install 32 bit version?

Comment: Install the 64bit Driver; http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
```

refers to the older Access "Jet" driver which is installed as part of Windows itself but is only available to 32-bit applications. (There is no 64-bit version of Jet.)

You could download and install the 64-bit version of the newer Access Database Engine (a.k.a. "ACE", available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255)) and then use

```
Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)
```

as the driver name. (Assuming that the WAMP server does not already have a copy of Access 2007 or later installed on it.)

Comment: I had to uninstall office2010 32bit version for installing this driver but now it is working fine..